# SVG image format animation not working in IE11

Tags: animation, svg

I created a simple SVG animation image file and unfortunately I found that though it is displaying the animation is not working in ie11. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css">
    .track{fill:#D1D3D4;}
    .marker{fill:#899FBC;}
</style>

<path class="track" d="M50,0C22.4,0,0,22.4,0,50s22.4,50,50,50s50-22.4,50-50S77.6,0,50,0z M50,95.2C25,95.2,4.8,75,4.8,50
    S25,4.7,50,4.7S95.2,25,95.2,50S75,95.2,50,95.2z"/>

    <path class="marker" d="M95.2,50h4.8c0-27.6-22.4-50-50-50v4.8C75,4.7,95.2,25,95.2,50z">

    <animateTransform
        attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        from="0 50 50"
        to="360 50 50"
        dur=".8s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
    />

</path>

</svg>
```

Comment: IE does not support SMIL natively. There's a polyfill called [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) that can give SMIL support to IE.